# Question about net distance types of electromagnetic radiation travels

Tags: wavelength

I was comparing the periods of types of electromagnetic radiation and I noticed that types with longer wavelengths seem to travel a greater net distance for each period. Does this mean that types of electromagnetic radiation with longer wavelengths travel quicker to a certain point than electromagnetic radiation with shorter wavelengths?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the period is *also* longer, leaving the ratio of wavelength to period constant and equal to the speed of light. The equation

$$\frac{\lambda}{T}=c$$

holds for *all* wavelengths.

Answer (score 0):

All electromagnetic frequencies travel at the speed of light $c$. The radiation with longer wavelength $\lambda$ has a lower frequency $\nu$, such that $$\lambda\nu = c$$
(The period $T$ is just the inverse of the frequency, 
$T = \frac{1}{\nu}$)